What is the highest ZooKeeper clean up frequency
I am currently dealing with an issue where occasionally a system using ZooKeeper will generate are large number of snapshots and transaction log files. These take up disk space that we would like to free up as quickly as possible.
Currently, we have the ZK Clean up task set to a 1 hour period. Is this highest frequency ZooKeeper will allow? If we can run Clean up more frequently, then are there any consequences to be aware of?
